# Android: GridView - OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-gridview

I have to show about 40 bitmaps in a Gridview. each image is around 500k and total size is around 15MB. I am getting OutOfMemoryError in my getView() of Adapter.
(I'm reusing the convertView).

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: How big are the bitmaps? Width and Height

Comment: Why not use either the [Lazy Loader](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) or the [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)? That will simplify the part where you have to deal with _Out Of Memory_ issues....

Comment: For the mobiles using API greater or equal to 11 you can use this tag in manifest at application lever :-  android:largeHeap="true"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your device do not support maintaining the 40bitmaps in memory. You should implement it loading only visibles imagenes.

If you don't know how to do it, you can use [Android Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). This library will avoid outOfMemoryError and will simplify the load image task.